Uniform and absolute convergence of a given complex series
Considering $r>1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{z}{(1-z)^n}$; my goal is to show that this series converges absolutely and uniformly on $\mathbb{C}- \overline{D(1,r)}$.
I tried using the Weierstrass M-test:
$$\frac{|z|}{|1-z|^n} < \frac{|z|}{r^n}$$
But this would only lead to uniform convergence on a bounded domain which is not the case. Any suggestions?

$ \dfrac{|z|}{|1-z|^n} < \dfrac{|z|}{r^n}$ is equivalent to $|1 - z| > r$.

Note that $$\left|\dfrac{z}{(1-z)^n}\right|=\left|\dfrac{-z}{(1-z)^n}\right|=\left|\dfrac{1-z}{(1-z)^n}-\dfrac{1}{(1-z)^n}\right|\leq \left|\dfrac{1-z}{(1-z)^n}\right|+\left|\dfrac{1}{(1-z)^n}\right|=\\ \dfrac{1}{|1-z|^{n-1}}+\dfrac{1}{|1-z|^n}\leq \dfrac{1}{r^{n-1}}+\dfrac{1}{r^n}$$
Applying the Weierstrass M-test now yields the desired uniform and absolute convergence.

Hint: $\frac{z}{(1-z)^n}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^n}-\frac{1-z}{(1-z)^n}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^n}-\frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-1}}$.
